# See Google Image search results with better resolution

Tags: google-image-search

When I do a Google Images search, the results are fuzzy, even if I enlarge with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.  How can I get a higher resolution preview?  Perhaps a browser extension or a search parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Image previews (called thumbnails) you see in Google Image search are no bigger than **200×200px**. This results in fuzziness you experience when you zoom in your view. It's like you would watch a video file of resolution 426×240 (240p) on 200" TV (eg. not a good idea).

You should go for an extension called Hover Zoom+ which is able to show you full an image behind the thumbnail and all of that without even single click - just point your cursor on the image and wait 0.5 seconds (wait time can be lowered in settings)

- **https://github.com/extesy/hoverzoom/**
- **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hover-zoom%20/pccckmaobkjjboncdfnnofkonhgpceea)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google's "Search Tools" to filter by image size, selecting "Large" for higher resolution results. If you wish to increase the resolution of the preview images specifically, a browser extension like "Google Search 'View Image' Button" can be helpful. This reintroduces the "View Image" button, allowing you to view images in their full resolution directly.